# How to make Blender exit after running Python script from command line?

Tags: python, command-line

I have the problem that Blender does not exit after executing in background mode from command line.

For example this command:

```
./blender -b -P test.py
```

gives me this output, but does not exit Blender:

```
Read prefs: /home/mbc/.config/blender/2.79/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /usr/local/blender/blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python
Hello world
```

My Python test script is very simple:

```
import bpy
print("Hello world")
```

Even if I don't run a Python script but just render a single frame, the Blender process does not exit.

I am running **blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-x86_64** on **Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS** with linux image version 4.4.0-112-lowlatency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`?

Comment: Thanks! I could not find that in the API documentation myself. However, as I wrote in my answer below, Blender does quit by itself when I work around the audio-related hang problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was something wrong with my audio setup in Linux. I run JACK via QJackCtl.

If I run Blender from the command line with the `-noaudio` switch, it exits on completion like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case on my Windows10 as well.  If I run the following script:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()
```

using the command:

```
blender --noaudio --python myscript.py
```

it will exit without prompting with the "Do you really want to quit?" prompt.  If I omit the `--noaudio` option it always prompts.  I might suggest that we consider adding an optional **force** parameter to `quit_blender()`

Comment: If I add the -b option on the command line then it doesn't prompt.  Of course, it also doesn't display the window.  So prompting seems to be connected to both GUI and presence of audio.